# How can I search Google Maps API and get multiple places?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-places

I've been able to make requests to the Places API from Google Maps, but I always get one result.

For example, searching something like "The White House", or an actual street address, get one single result:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json
  ?input=the%20white%20house
  &inputtype=textquery
  &fields=formatted_address,name,geometry
  &key=API_KEY

response: {
  candidates: [
    {
      formatted_address: "1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW, Washington, DC 20500, USA",
      geometry: {
        location: {
          lat: 38.8976763,
          lng: -77.0365298
        },
        viewport: {
          northeast: {
            lat: 38.90148105,
            lng: -77.03520012010728
          },
          southwest: {
            lat: 38.89640805000001,
            lng: -77.03789977989273
          }
        }
      },
      name: "The White House"
    }
  ],
  status: "OK"
};
```

What if I want to find, to be cliche, all the Starbucks around me? (how to limit the search radius is a later question)

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json
  ?input=starbucks
  &inputtype=textquery
  &fields=formatted_address,name,geometry
  &key=API_KEY

response: {
  candidates: [],
  status: "ZERO_RESULTS"
};
```

Some comments indicate that I should be getting a different response for my "Starbucks" search. Why aren't I?

Comment: The geocoder expects an address as an input, and will in most cases only return the single closest match.  Not sure how you are testing the Places API, but I usually get 20 results for "starbucks" (using `SearchBox`). Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Related question: [google maps javascript api v3 places library deosn't return any results for the bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12613127/google-maps-javascript-api-v3-places-library-deosnt-return-any-results-for-the)

Comment: @geocodezip `findplacefromtext` expects not an address as an input but the 'name, address, or category of establishments' (from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-find-place#required-parameters)

Comment: I also get only 1 result e.g. for https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=restaurant&inputtype=textquery&fields=name%2Cformatted_address&locationbias=circle%3A10000%4040.809480%2C-73.949341&key=API_KEY .maybe it's because of the trial API key?

Comment: at the same time for same search but for `textsearch` I get 20 results: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?location=40.809480%2C-73.949341&radius=10000&types=restaurant&key=API_kEY

Comment: what's the difference between `search` and `textsearch` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [**Nearby Search**](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests). Just please note that there is no way to constrain Nearby Search requests to only return specific fields.

Just look at the sample request below:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=38.8976763%2C-77.0365298&radius=50000&keyword=mcdonalds&key=YOUR_KEY

The response will give you all McDonalds store in this specific location 38.8976763,-77.0365298. You will also notice that there's a ***radius*** parameter of 50000 to return the place results.

Comment: As far as I know, the max value for the radius is 50000, which is not a lot. So, you can't get all the multiple places in a country. Is there another way to do that?

Comment: Grigory Zhadko, did you find a strategy for that?